# TWebBrowser + SaveToImage from Google Static Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, delphi, delphi-xe5

In my program, developed in FireMonkey Mobile, I have a TWebBrowser which happened a URL of a static google map.

Example:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false

I need a picture of that which is shown in the browser. How do I?

Comment: The WebView downloaded the png picture to display it. Why don't you download the picture yourself and save to file?

Comment: The map will show in a TWebBrowser, located on a form in my program. I'm not showing in another browser where I have the functionality and download the image

Comment: I knew that all already. I suggested what you could do instead. You are not commenting on that.

Answer (score 0):

With Delphi on Android, you can use the Indy HTTP client class TIdHTTP do download the PNG file. (This requires that the URL is available in a string variable in your app).

Then you only need to instantiate and configure the HTTP client and execute a HTTP GET request on that URL. The HTTP response will contain a stream of the image file. There should be plenty of example about binary data download with Indy on the web.